# How to consume a service registered in wsO2 G-Reg

Tags: wso2

Use case:

1) One webservice running on tomcat server say on machine1
2) I registered this webservice on wsO2 Greg, registry is running on machine 2
3) I also attached a ws-security policy 'UserNameToken' to the service through registry.
4) Now I want to write a client for the webservice using Eclipse

I have created a registry client and retrieved the Service object. I am also able to get the attachedPolicies for that Service object.
My question or doubt is how to consume that webservice on whom the policy has been applied.

Code snippet as follows:

```
        Service[] services1 = serviceManager
                .findServices(new ServiceFilter() {
                    public boolean matches(Service service)
                            throws GovernanceException {

                        String version = service
                                .getAttribute("overview_version");
                        String name = service.getAttribute("overview_name");
                        String nameSpaceofService = service
                                .getAttribute("overview_namespace");
                        return (version != null
                                && version.equals(version_no)
                                && name.equals(sserviceName) && nameSpaceofService
                                .equals(nameSpace));
                    }
                });

        Service fastThoughtService = services1[0];
        Policy[] policyArray = fastThoughtService.getAttachedPolicies();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another Service client to consume the web service publish at tomcat. Registry just keeps the metadata of the Service. You need to generate or create client according to the WSDL publish at the Service implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Greg only stores metadata and is not able to provide the webservice itself (without installing metiadion features).
What you have to do is define a proxy service in ESB (separate sor installing ESB features in GREG)